# SSIS Script Component works locally but fails on server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a relatively simple script component that works fine in development but deployed as a project to the destination SQL Server does not.

> Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Relatively simple here, reading in a resource, deserializing as Json, and populating the buffer. Again, the code works fine locally, does not deployed and ran from the server. Also, the job itself otherwise works fine. Any thoughts? Thanks.

**Update**: Added System.Memory using gacutil, then it complained about System.Buffers.dll, so I added that too, then System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll but it still complains about that one, same error just that dll rather than System.Memory.dll

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    var jsonResource = SC_230dc9a1d6584d51a25f503b07cf64c4.Properties.Resources.countriesV1;
    using (var jsonStream = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(jsonResource, 0, jsonResource.Length)))
    {
        var countriesV1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<RestCountry>>(jsonStream.ReadToEnd());
        foreach (var row in countriesV1)
        {
            RestCountriesBuffer.AddRow();
            RestCountriesBuffer.common = row.name.common;
            RestCountriesBuffer.cca2 = row.cca2;
            RestCountriesBuffer.cca3 = row.cca3;
            RestCountriesBuffer.ccn3 = row.ccn3;
        }
    }
}
public class RestCountry
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public string cca2 { get; set; }
    public string ccn3 { get; set; }
    public string cca3 { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string common { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `JsonSerializer` part of Newtonsoft nuget package, yes?

Comment: @billinkc Using System.Text.Json from Framework 4.7.2. See update.

Comment: Can you confirm that the target server has a 4.7.2 runtime installed?

Comment: @billinkc it does yes